# Browning of leaves of corn plant

Tags: dracaena, corn

[image: plant] i was watering my plant today and noticed this. The weather has been hot lately and I'm not sure if this is leaf spot disease or just too much sunlight. Any help please? Thank you!

Comment: Not what corn means at least two places I can think of, one of which I live in.

Comment: I would just trim the affected leaves on your dracaena and hope it does not recur. I have had dracaena for  many decades and never saw that deterioration